# How do I proceed with the question I asked?

Tags: support, specific-question

Here's the question:

[DTD for a custom meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45988561/dtd-for-a-custom-meta-tag?noredirect=1#comment78957942_45988561)

I received no answers on this question, but several comments that clarified the issue for me. I didn't want to leave the question open... because it was answered, and I didn't want to delete it, because I think this could be a useful question / answer for others. So I added my own answer, and attributed the solution to the comments. I've come back this morning to find my answer deleted. What do I do now?

Comment: You just confirmed it was solved, which is great, but if you're answering - Maybe include the actual details in the answer itself

Comment: Your question is unclear anyway. You mention a DTD, but the sample markup gives no indication of which version of HTML you're using, because like I said the only possible version in which the syntax is actually valid *doesn't* use DTD (the alternative is XHTML, the only dialect that *does* let you customize DTDs being based on XML). Note that this is *notwithstanding* your self-answer; the question itself still needs to make clear what you understand of HTML, even if that understanding is flawed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Self-answering doesn't change [our requirements for what makes a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

In other words, the answer still needs to be complete and self-contained. The relevant information from the comments either needs to be summarized or quoted, so that it appears directly in the body of your answer. (Either way, you would need to give credit to the person who originally left the comment, but you got that part right the first time.)

Because your answer didn't meet our standards, it was flagged and deleted by community members reviewing low-quality posts.* If you edit it and fix the problems with it, then it can be undeleted.

As you said, if the question and answer may be useful to others, then it should continue to exist and have a good answer!

__
<sub>* Granted, the auto-comment that one of the reviewers chose to leave was wrong and very misleading. They should have been paying more attention. Sorry about that. I've removed it now.</sub>